# GCP Pub/Sub default service account is not getting created when enabling the API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, service-accounts

We have two projects in our GCP account; one for our Dev environment and one for our Test environment at the moment. Terraform manages most of our infrastructure, so we have minimal clicking around the GUI, or CLI commands.

I have assumed we enabled the Pub/Sub API by deploying to it with Terraform in both of our environments, although we may have needed to do this manually. We noticed that Google created a default Pub/Sub service account for us in our Dev environment, but not in our Test environment. [This docs page suggests it should make this service account](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/push#setting_up_for_push_authentication).

Additionally, we have noticed multiple Pub/Sub subscriptions working, apparently without any service account. We believe that the service account is only needed for this particular Subscription because it is a push to an e-mail server. Therefore, it needs a service account with the  'Service Account Token Creator' role.

We've attempted to redeploy the whole infrastructure and disable/re-enable the Pub/Sub API. Neither seemed to kick GCP into creating the Service Account. Further to this, we attempted to make the default service account manually. Still, GCP constrains the name a user can give a service account themselves, so we're unable to create a service account with the name that the Pub/Sub service would expect.

We wonder if there is some configuration of the project we may have missed or if anyone has seen this previously?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Does it not exist or does you not see it?

I'm pretty sure that it exists but without any role granted on it and you don't see it in the UI. Try to grant a role on this default service account, and it will appear in the IAM page!

Comment: Yeh, it was an option we thought of. It really does not exists, even when you click the 'Include Google-provided role grants' flag in the top right of IAM's. 

We attempted to attach the role, by guessing the name of the service account, unfortunately, it caused our build to fail.

Comment: Scratch that... on the second attempt, it seems that assigning the role to an apparently non-existent Service Account will un-earth the Service Account!

Comment: @Joe Service accounts do not appear in IAM if they do not have project related roles assigned. They do appear under "IAM & Admin" -> "Service Accounts". Google Cloud does not hide service accounts.

Comment: Kudos to Allison Fisher (https://stackoverflow.com/users/14018476/allison-fisher), the GCP engineer who reached out to me directly and explained what was going on. To add context to @Guillaume's correct answer   "The service account exists, but is not visible to you before you grant a role on it. This is because the Pub/Sub service account does not live in your project. Since the service account doesn't belong to your project, it will not show up in your IAM > Service Accounts tab and only appears in your project's IAM Permissions page once you've assigned it a role in your project."